# Encrypt with angular CryptoJS and decrypt with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ionic-framework, mcrypt, cryptojs

I'm encrypting the data in ECB 256 AES using a key in the javascript and decrypting at php using the username and key. It is encrypting but i'm failing to decrypt in the php.

I'm trying to do this in ionic app.

In app.js in config:

```
.config(['$cryptoProvider', function($cryptoProvider){
$cryptoProvider.setCryptographyKey('ABCD1234567890EF');
```

}])

In controller:

```
var encryptedUsername = $crypto.encrypt(username);
var key = 'ABCD1234567890EF';
```

In php:

```
$username = $_POST['encryptedUsername'];
$key =$_POST['key'];

function fnDecrypt($sValue, $sSecretKey)
{
return rtrim(
    mcrypt_decrypt(
        MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, 
        $sSecretKey, 
        base64_decode($sValue), 
        MCRYPT_MODE_ECB
    ), "\0"
);
}

$plaintext = fnDecrypt($username, $key);
echo $plaintext;
```

please tell me where I'm making a mistake.

Comment: Note that `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256` is not AES anymore. The 256 is the block size in this case and has nothing to do with the key size of AES-256. CryptoJS uses CBC mode by default and not ECB mode.

Comment: I don't know that thanks @ArtjomB. can you please tell me if  there is any way to work with only key and string to decrypt in php? because while encrypting i have only used string and key.

Comment: I've edited my answer in the linked question. Now it includes proper parsing of the ciphertext.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Thanks.. I checked your answer but its giving me evpKDF as undefined. I'm also confused between $ciphertext and $password. Please tell me which one is string and which one is key?

Comment: `evpKDF` is defined in the first part of my answer. `$password` is supposed to be the password, which is the same thing that you set with `$cryptoProvider.setCryptographyKey`. The naming here is misleading, because this is not an actual key. That is why I named it `$password`

Comment: @ArtjomB. Please check this https://github.com/middleout/angular-cryptography... I have followed this for the encryption... In this they have not used any IV or salt or padding. So I'm trying to do the decryption part in php but not getting that... please tell me how to solve this problem. As i don't what know the blocksize or padding what they have used in it

Comment: IV and salt are randomly generated by CryptoJS. The salt is stored in front of the ciphertext, which needs to be parsed. I've edited my answer to include that parsing, so I don't understand what the issue is. All the code is there.

Comment: �5��e���p���� this is the $decryptPassword i got... @ArtjomB. input i gave it as "es"

Comment: Can you give an example ciphertext and the accompanying "key" that you use in Angular?

Comment: @ArtjomB. The string that i'm encrypting is "es" and the key i'm using to encrypt is "ABCD1234".... the encrypted value is "U2FsdGVkX1/I+kQLVKwyexQ3zKYm0AZSyDdoRCuf+/A=" and the decrypted value I got is "�P�/���_�x7:"

Comment: @ArtjomB. thanks! Its working now... the problem was $salt = substr($ciphertext, 8, 16);.... it should have been this $salt = substr($ciphertext, 8, 8); Thanks alot!

Comment: Sorry about that. It's a common bug, because there is a 50-50 split between APIs that use length and APIs that use a "to-index (exclusive)".